# When launching Spring app (STS) with embedded Tomcat, both java.exe and javaw.exe processes are created on the same port

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, javaw

As the title says - when launching Spring app (STS) with embedded Tomcat, both java.exe and javaw.exe processes are created on the same port.

That means I have troubles with busy port, even when using the Relaunch option (which typically shuts Tomcat down and then restarts it). Indeed, relaunching does stop one of the two processes but then I get an error stating that the port must be busy. Killing the remaining one does solve the issue but I life is too short to both develop in Java AND kill the process manually.

Is there a convenient way to overcome this? I see that is STS (and Eclipse too, of course) there's a way to specify project specific JRE but I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Note: I have both 32- and 64-bit java8 instances installed.

Comment: Have you tried launching it as a java application (ie, just run `main`)?  It sounds like you are deploying it on Tomcat, while at the same time there is an embedded Tomcat being started...

Comment: @john16384 Running it as a java application worked - a single process was created. It's interesting because prior to today's reinstall (actually new download of the same (most recent) version of STS) I was running it as usual - through a Maven goal: `install spring-boot:run` and it worked without issues (I do remember however these same issues on rare occasions). Thank you, you are invited to create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure why that could have happened since the new update, but I'm glad it solved the issue anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it as a java application (ie, just run main).

It sounds like you are deploying it on Tomcat, while at the same time there is an embedded Tomcat being started... :)

Comment: STS has a "Run As Boot App" which is pretty much the same as "Run As Java" but provides some extra bells and whistles. For a better integration with STS (e.g. the boot dashboard ui) its probably best to use "Run As Boot App" instead of "Run as Java".

Comment: That sounds to me like it is a better answer.  I don't personally use STS so I wasn't aware of that option.